# Different xquery result between Let and For when using "every" clause

Tags: xml, xquery

I have the following Xquery:

```
let $x := <a>
           <i>false</i>
          </a>
return
    if (every $t in $x/a satisfies $t/i eq "true")
    then $x
    else <nothing/>
```

How I interpret this is, return `$x` if all `<a>` have an `<i>` that has the word "true". However, this always return `$x`.

In contrast, if I have the following XML doc:

```
<root>
  <a><i>false</i></a>
</root>
```

and the following query:

```
for $x in /root
return
    if (every $t in $x/a satisfies $t/i eq "true" )
    then $x
    else <nothing/>
```

It will return `<nothing/>` when `<i>` contains false and will return `$x` when `<i>` is "true"

My questions are:

1. Why does the query with "let" behave the way it does?
2. Why does the query with "for" behave differently?

Comment: The quantifier expressions are different in these two queries. That would be the first reason they don't behave the same. Also, there is a syntax error in the first query.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the inconsistencies and any syntax errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key difference is the existence of a root element assigned to $x in the second example, but not in the first.

In your first example the root element is `<a>`, but in your quantifier expression you write `every $t in $x/a`. `$x/a` selects child `a` elements of `<a>`, and there are none (only `i`). So `$x/a` evaluates to empty. The expression is reduced to `every $t in () satisfies $t/i eq "true"`. Since empty is assigned to `$t` the full quantifier expression evaluates to true.